# How to check that a input is Positive Integer?

Tags: if-statement, while-loop, try-catch, valueerror

a part of my code is as follow I want to raise a errorvalue if the user doesnt enter a Positive integer for x & Y
when I dont check a positive input this code act ok for raising value error incase of inputing Float Number instead of a Integer
but when I add if for checking x and y for beign positive this code is not running anymore

the mentioned part of my code is:

```
while True:
    try:
        A, B = moudle(x=int(input('x:')), y=int(input('y:')))
        print('The x is ' + str(x))
        print('The y is ' + str(y))
        break 
    except ValueError:
        print("insert Positive Integer Number.  Try again...")
```

```
while True:
    try:
        A, B = moudle(x=int(input('x:')), y=int(input('y:')))
        print('The x is ' + str(x))
        print('The y is ' + str(y))
        break 
    except ValueError:
        print("insert Positive Integer Number.  Try again...")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to your problem; just use conditional statements for it:

```
num = int(input("Enter the number \n "))
if num >= 0:
    print("The number is positive")

elif num < 0:
   print("The number is negative")
```

Comment: Thanks, I have two variables that need to be input, also I need to raise value error as far as the user is inputting negative value